# check if a segment is a number

Tags: stash, variable, global-variables

I am trying to figure out a way to set to variable values depending on if a specific segment is a number or not.  First how to I check if the segment 2 is a number or not?  I want to apply this type of logic

```
if segment_2 is a number
    {exp:stash:set name="this_url_title" value=""}
    {exp:stash:set name="this_entry_id" value="{segment_2}"}
else
    {exp:stash:set name="this_url_title" value="{segment_2}"}
    {exp:stash:set name="this_entry_id" value=""}
end
```

Then use the 2 variables in a channel entries tag like so.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="off" entry_id='{exp:stash:get name="this_entry_id"}' url_title='{exp:stash:get name="this_url_title"}' parse="inward"}
```

So I can either pass an entry_id or a url_title in the segment to view the channel entry.

I tried hard coding the stash variables and passing them in the entries tag but I get no results.  I tried hard coding them to this:

```
{exp:stash:set name="this_url_title"}{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:stash:set name="this_entry_id"}123{/exp:stash:set}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [matches operator](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#matches-operator), which was added in EE v2.9.0:

```
{if segment_2 ~ "/^\d+$/"}
    [...]
{/if}
```

Comment: Good call, for reference the matches operator was added in EE v2.9.0

Comment: Cool, I was not aware you could do regular expression with comparators. I ended up with: {if segment_2 ~ "/^\d+$/"} without the / at the beginning and the end I got error: Something has gone wrong and this URL cannot be processed at this time.

Comment: I'm sorry about it! I simply forgot! I'm sorry!